# Can Anyone Tell me why my changelights is not defined?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>
  <p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

  <img id="D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\RedLights.jpg" src=D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\RedLights.jpg>

  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLights()">ChangeLights</button>

  <script>
    var list = ["D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\RedLights.jpg", "D:\ComputerScience\JavaScrip tExtras\RedAmberLights.jpg", "D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\GreenLights.jpg", "D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\AmberLights.jpg"]

    var count: 0, 1

    function ChangeLights() {
      var image = document.getElementById('D:\ComputerScience\JavaScriptExtras\RedLights.jpg');
    }
    if list = 0 {
      image.src = list[0];
    }
    if list = 1 {
      image.src = list[1];
    } else if list = 2 {
      image.src = list[2];
    } else >3 {
      image.src = list[3];
    }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Im looking at my code and it runs and shows me the right light however im it does not change from red to anything else. when i run an error code on google chrome it says that changelights is not defined. Ive been staring at the code for days and if anybody knows why changelights is not defined id be thanking you forever.If you can tidy up the code for me that would be much appreciated too

Comment: What is `var count:0,1` ? It throws error. You can't define variable like this.

Comment: Also, afaik, there's no way other than the File API for JS to load resources off the client computer. This code shouldn't run, at all.

Comment: Execution of your Javascript code ends at `var count:0,1` which is invalid Javascript. What's it supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: The `src` attribute from the `img` tag is missing quotes. Furthermore you have to escape all backslashes.

Comment: The `if` statements should be corrected to `if (list==0) ... `. Beside that there's a closing curly that doesn't belong there.

Comment: If you use Stack Snippets (icon with `<>` in a page), there's a Tidy button that will tidy your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are really a lot of syntax errors in your code that it is hard to tell what the code should achieve. I changed a lot to make it work but is just a guess that it does now what you want it to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>
  <p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>
  <img id="lightimg" src="file:///D:/ComputerScience/JavaScriptExtras/RedLights.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLights()">ChangeLights</button>
  <script>
    var list = [
       "file:///D:/ComputerScience/JavaScriptExtras/RedLights.jpg",
       "file:///D:/ComputerScience/JavaScriptExtras/RedAmberLights.jpg",
       "file:///D:/ComputerScience/JavaScriptExtras/GreenLights.jpg", 
       "file:///D:/ComputerScience/JavaScriptExtras/AmberLights.jpg"
    ];
    var count = 0;

    function ChangeLights() {
      var image = document.getElementById('lightimg');
      image.src = list[count];
      count++;
      if (count >= list.length)
        count = 0;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

These are some of the things I changed:

- Removed the comparisons with `list` variable in `ChangeLights`.
- Changed the `id` of the `img` tag to "lightimg" to avoid backslashes in id name
- Converted the URLs to local file URLs (`file:///`)

Comment: The img element should fail because of the local path, shouldn't it? If this were possible, JS could fetch arbitrary data from the client's computer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  Depends on your environment. I would prefer local paths but I wanted that you can recognize some parts from the original code :-)